# Android web app icon being cut off the edges

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, web-applications, android-launcher

I am making a web app, and when I "add to Home Screen" on my android device, the icon of my app is not being displayed properly. Below is the screenshot of it, and below that is what the icon really should look like:

[image]

[image]

This is the code I have inside the head tag of my website:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="192x192" href="mydomain.com/img/site-icon/nice-highres.png">
```

Comment: The head tag of the webpage is no visible for the launcher, so there must be something what generates an icon for your app. What is it?

Comment: I have no idea. here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen
it says that if I set the link tag in my head and press "add to Home screen" in my browser, it will show the icon in my home screen of my android device

Comment: In that case I have misunderstood your question. I thought you mean you've converted your webpage to an android app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked around the [Add to Homescreen](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#best-practices) page for a while but it doesn't really mention any behavior on how the icon is scaled, but I found a tutorial about [How to Add Icons](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/adding-an-icon-for-iphone-ipad-android-to-your-website/) and here, it mentions about creating the images available for all screen sizes:

> If you don’t want to create all these images, you should at least create the larger resolution ones. That way they’ll look good on the hi-res devices. The older devices **will load the closest size available to their required size and shrink them down** (this works but isn’t ideal if you want complete control and the fastest download).

Based from this, you can presume that the icon **MUST** automatically be scaled down depending on the screen size. I'm not quite sure about this, but maybe what is causing your icon to not scale properly is because the `rel` attribute in your `<link..>` is incorrect? As per your code, it shows as `rel="shortcut icon"` while as per the **Add to Homescreen** doc, it should be `rel="icon"`.

Also, a **configuration** is needed to support a homescreen launch, where you add some `<meta>` tags, like so (from the **Add to Homescreen doc**):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Awesome app </title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
     <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/icon.png">
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Care to try it out and let me know if it works. Hope this helps somehow though. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

On a specific device running Android 4.4.2 Jelly Bean, I found that the home screen icon would get cut off when the icon was larger than 92x92, even if 92x92 was also provided.

So just having this produces a great looking icon on the Jelly Bean device.

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="92x92" href="/favicon-92.png">
```

But the following will result in favicon-128.png being used on the Jelly Bean device, with the right and bottom sides being cropped. However, this does work on newer version of Android, as it should.

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="/favicon-128.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="92x92" href="/favicon-92.png">
```

Since my web app is targeting a specific device running Jelly Bean, I decided to only provide the 92x92 icon. For websites in general I would recommend following [Google's advice](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#fallback) and provide low-res and high-res icons, which could cause issues on Jelly Bean devices.

Answer (score 1):

When you size your logo with Android Studio they have a scale feature.

To size your logo:

1: Right-click app folder
2: Hover over "new" and click "create image asset"

Then resize with this tool:

[image: scale_image]

Answer (score 0):

as explained here (https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons), the icon dimension may be 48dp (and least for dense layout!).

After, the max size is relative to the user launcher...

I don't know what are the "perfect" dimensions in px (which are relative to the screen), but you may try to resize it by 48/48 (and also replace the "sizes" attribute)

Comment: I followed this article and here, 192px times 192px is recommended. I've tried making the image and replacing the size attribute to smaller number, but then the icon got really small

Comment: Ok, it is something that I don't know very well... So what is your device? Do you use a custom launcher? The problem can come from here...

Can you set the icon in your activity code? Import it with android Studio (it will be stored in different sizes, for the different viewports), I think it is the best solution, because it's supporting a larger amount of devices...